# Use if case with a @ViewBuilder so I can use it for a view property

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've got a couple of handy methods to use when I want to add properties with a condition in a view.

This is one of them:

```
    /// Applies the given transform if the given condition evaluates to `true`.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - condition: The condition to evaluate.
    ///   - transform: The transform to apply to the source `View`.
    /// - Returns: Either the original `View` or the modified `View` if the condition is `true`.
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
```

I tried to do an adaptation with a `if case` so it would work with any enum. But I didn't get very far because of the nature of the enums.

In my particular case I've got an enum with associated variables.

So I would like to use it like this:

```
Text("Hello world")
.ifCase(myEnumVar = .MyEnumCase(_), transform: { view
view.foregroundColor(Color.red)
})
```

Any hints how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: with a `ViewModifier`

Answer (score 0):

This can help?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello world")
                .ifCase(.MyEnumCase("cc")) { view in
                    view.foregroundColor(.red)
                }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func ifCase<Content: View>(_ myEnumVar: MyEnumCase, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if myEnumVar == .MyEnumCase("cc") {
               transform(self)
           } else {
               self
           }
       }
}

enum MyEnumCase {
    case MyEnumCase(String?)
}


extension MyEnumCase: Equatable {
    #warning("TODO: To be implemented")
}
```

I don't understand if you want a more generic component.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something more generic to allow any enum